# JavaFX print API doesn't cancel saving/printing screen properly. It still brings up the window to choose directory to save in

Tags: java, javafx

I've recently started using the Javafx printing API to export something to a PDF file and/or print the screen. It works fine when you decide to save/print, but when you click cancel on the window that has you choose where to save or print to, it still pops up the window to choose a directory to name and save the file into.

I have the function linked to a On Mouse Clicked event through the FXML file, but I don't think that is the issue.

here is the code I currently have:

```
public void printSaveDiagram() {
    System.out.println("printing/saving file!");
    // Create the Printer Job
    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

    // Get The Printer Job Settings
    JobSettings jobSettings = printerJob.getJobSettings();

    PageLayout pageLayout;
    if (printerJob != null) {

        printerJob.showPrintDialog(Controller.stage);

        // Get The Printer
        Printer printer = printerJob.getPrinter();
        // Create the Page Layout of the Printer
        pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.C, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE,Printer.MarginType.EQUAL);
        jobSettings.setPageLayout(pageLayout);
        printerJob.printPage(diagram);
        printerJob.endJob();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you do not test the return of `printerJob.showPrintDialog(Controller.stage);`. Please have a look on the [documentation of this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrinterJob.html#showPrintDialog-javafx.stage.Window-)

Comment: @Pagbo thank you. I assume it would look something like this then: if(printerJob.showPrintDialog(Controller.stage)== false){printerJob.endJob();}

Comment: Actually, I am pretty sure it is not necessary to call this method because there will be 0 started job. By reading the doc it seems it does not matter if you call it, but `printerJob.endJob();` will be the same as `printerJob.cancelJob()`. Have a try and analyze the return values ;).

Comment: I just tested that line a said earlier, and it appears to work how I expected it to. I’ll try it without the method later and see if that changes anything also.